# file sharing from ubuntu 16.04LTS to Windows 7

Tags: 16.04

How can I share my windows pc files to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS pc using network sharing?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:
-- Install "Dropbox". It runs on both Devices.

or:

-- Plug a USB-Stick into your Router. It's accessible via

the file manager on your **ubuntu** Desktop by choosing "+ other locations"

**Windows** Explorer, open folder "Network"